# spring RestTemplate vender specific Media type headers not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

I am trying to convert my jersey api call to spring boot resttemplate client call, when i am trying to add vender specific header its saying unsupported media type.
i tried like this

```
  HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.ALL));
  headers.setContentType(MediaType.ALL); 
  HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("parameters", headers);
  ResponseEntity<Admin> result = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, Admin.class);
```

i even tried diffrent combinations of Media types but it did not worked i also tried to add media type like  `MediaType.parseMediaType("application/vnd.....);`
please provide some help in this.please let me know what is httpMessage converter and how to add this to our custom vender specific media types.

Comment: When asking about an error, post the exact and complete error. I don't see any vendor specific header in the code you posted BTW. And setting the content type to ALL doesn't make much sense.

Comment: how to set  headers.setContentType(MediaType.(VENDORSPECIFIC TYPE)). header.setContentType() Expecting Media type object to be passed as a parameter. so i tried to add like this(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/vnd.....)) still giving exception

Comment: Again, post your actual code (not just a truncated part of it), and the actual, complete, exact error.

Answer (score 3):

You won't be able to set a custom content type with `setContentType(MediaType mediaType)` since it accepts a `MediaType` object, which your custom MediaType cannot be converted into.

You can use the below to set the custom content type:

```
headers.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/custom");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:
`headers.setContentType(MediaType.valueOf(VENDOR_MEDIA_TYPE));`

Comment: `MediaType.valueOf(VENDOR_MEDIA_TYPE)` uses `MediaType.parseMediaType(VENDOR_MEDIA_TYPE)` internally. So if the latter fails, so would the former.

Comment: Please edit your answer to provide an explanation of how this code solves the problem. This will make your answer more useful and understandable for the OP and for anyone in future.